# Превышение лимита типа long

Tags: java

Подскажите, может я что-нибудь не заметил. Ниже есть два фрагмента кода, по сути они выполняют одно и то же действие: находят значение сотого элемента последовательности чисел типа long. Последовательность задается следующим образом: каждый следующий элемент равен предыдущему, умноженному на 3 + 1.

Например:

a1 = 5;

a2 = a1*3+1;

a3 = a2*3+1;

```
    long[] massive = new long[100];
    massive[0] = 5;
    for(int h = 1; h<100; h++)
    {
        massive[h] = massive[h-1]*3 + 1;
    }
```

И значение **massive[99]** получается *-5471808550152166316l* (по идее значение превышает лимит типа long и принимает отрицательное значение, и так может продолжаться по кругу, как я понял)

```
    long a = 5;
    int f = 1; 
    while (f <= 100) 
    { 
        a = 3*a + 1;  
        f++; 
    }
```

Тут после завершения цикла значение **а** равняется *2031318423253052669l*

Почему значения отличаются? Я что-то не заметил?

Comment: while (f <= 100)  уберите =

Comment: Таки да, в while у вас на одну итерацию больше

Comment: @andreymal спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так равны

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    long[] massive = new long[100];
    massive[0] = 5;
    for (int h = 1; h < 100; h++) {
      massive[h] = massive[h - 1] * 3 + 1;
    }
    System.out.println(massive[99]);

    long a = 5;
    int f = 1;
    while (f < 100) {
      a = 3 * a + 1;
      f++;
    }

    System.out.println(a);
  }
```

Comment: Спасибо! Теперь все сошлось)